# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when creating a function

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i am just getting into programming and i have already reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 once, because it crashes everytime i create a template project and click in the line of the main function. when i create an empty project it crashes with any function as soon as i type the {} brakets.

It also wont create a c# project file. it just says "creating project x" forever.

what could cause this?

the installation took about 4 hours both times which seemed odd to me. ist that normal?

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Any reason this is tagged `c#` **AND** `c++`?

Comment: yes because my crash occurs with both these languages in the program.

Comment: You seem to have *different* problems with C# and C++. One is something taking a very long time (possibly forever), while the other seems to be a crash.. The two problems *may* be related, but it's impossible to say without more information (and no I don't know what information is really needed, haven't used Visual Studio in many years).

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2015 is it? What does the error say on the crash window? Windows event viewer should also show you the text of the crash.

Comment: so.. when trying to check the windows event viewer i got an error with the "snap-in". it recommended to remove and quit the snap-in and then the computer manager crashed..

VS15 also crashes when i try to open the toolbar on the left with the error: "The exeption "unknown software error" (0xe0434352) occured in the application at the position 0x7639c42d." (my native language is german so it might not be 1:1 what it typically would say)

Comment: th version is Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3

Comment: You probably have a dying hard drive or a stick of memory going bad in that case. Event viewer errors and the computer management window crashing is very unusual aside from hardware problems. You can go to the hard drive manufacturers website and find a tool that will test it for you, and back in the day I used [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) to test memory. There could be other hardware issues causing the same problems too; it's just very unlikely that ~core windows components start showing errors on a system unless it's hardware going bad. And it explains your VS issues too.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't say which template project are you trying to create, try creating a **Console Application** project:
File -> New -> Project

[image]

It will create the following starting code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the following lines into the Main function and run it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope you get this done, if not, there could be a lot of reasons why your Visual Studio crashes in that way, please share more information/screenshots if you can't do this and most important, which template are you trying to use.

Comment: I cant even create any c# template project. 
when i create a c++ console application project it crashes as soon as i try to type in the main function or in any way interact with any function (clicking the line)

Comment: i know this is not a lot of information but that all i have. It crashes as soon as i do anything! i cant write a single line of code or even create certain projects

Comment: mmm it looks like it is a problem not of Visual Studio.
Which version are you using? Try to use another different version, try the Community, or unistall completely VS and do a fresh install

Comment: the version is Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3

i have already uninstalled and reinstalled it.. my windows 7 should be up to date (recently updated)

Comment: did you do an absolutely clean installation? if so, then try with another version, as I said, it is difficult to know which the problem is. You will have to try to detect from where the problem comes :/